# Скрипты мешают отправке сообщений phpmailler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть проблема с отправкой писем с формы. Дело в том, что сразу после нажатия кнопки отправки, форме присваивается значение `display: none;` и отправка не происходит. Если я отключаю этот скрипт, то все работает исправно и письма доходят. Как решить проблему?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.do-submit').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.form-container').css({
      display: 'none',
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-container" action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <input class="form" 
         type="number" 
         name="user_phone" 
         placeholder="+7 (ххх) ххх хх хх" 
         required />
  <button type="submit" class="do-submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Зачем вам применять стили если при отправке идет перезагрузка страницы?

Comment: @Spartacus Чтобы часть страницы с формой исчезла, пока страница ждет ответа от сервера.

Comment: Есть методы отправки формы без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: @PavelBogdanov $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поведение, которое Вы описываете, не наблюдается. В Вашем скрипте есть строчка

```
event.preventDefault();
```

или

```
return false;
```

не включенная в вопрос.

Уберите эту строчку.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); есть, да